# Using Requests to submit form appears to return the original page

Tags: python, webforms, python-requests

I'm trying to use python to submit [this webform](https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/gisTools/gisAction.jsp?action=showNoNoticeRequiredToolForm).  But this is above my basic python skills and I can't seem to figure out why I'm just getting the original html returned me.

If you submit that form by hand using the parameters I have in my code below, you'll see that the following page contains the words "Results
You do not exceed Notice Criteria."  When I run the code below though, the output .txt file doesn't contain any of that statement in the html.  What am I missing? Thanks

```
import requests

url = r'https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/gisTools/gisAction.jsp?'\
    'action=showNoNoticeRequiredToolForm'    

payload = {
        'latD': 13,  
        'latM': 13,
        'latS': 13,
        'longD': 90,  
        'longM': 13,
        'longS': 13,
        'latDir': 'N',
        'longDir': 'W',
        'datum': 'NAD83',
        'siteElevation': 1300,  
        'unadjustedAgl': 13,
        'traverseway': 'NO',
        'onAirport': 'false'
        }

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
with open("results.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the GET part from the url? So `url = r'https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/gisTools/gisAction.jsp'`

Comment: Hey!  That got me on the right track, taking that out finally gave me updated html back which had a height error, turns out there's two hidden  parameters I needed to set as well and now it's good to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your URL contains some GET data.
Depending on how the webserver is programmed, this may cause the server to load the page for a GET request instead of a POST request.

Removing `?action=showNoNoticeRequiredToolForm` from the url will give you the correct response:

```
url = r'https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/gisTools/gisAction.jsp'
```